# how to keep images aligned correctly when screen size changes and using big picture

Tags: css, image, scroll, responsive-design, overlapping

I am making a website where big pictures are displayed and the previous one always overlaps a bit with the next one. what would be the best way to keep the whole website as responsive as possible.

I tried to make one long div and position each picture using relative position and then adjusting the position so it would overlap and be positioned correctly. But as soon as the screen size changes, this way doesn't work properly.

Any idea of alternatives?

Here is a picture of the idea:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXehD.png)

Thanks already for the help

Answer (score 0):

When using the properties `position: relative` and `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`, have you tried working with a responsive unit like `vw` (viewport width) or `vh` (viewport height)?

Something like this, e.g.:

```
.relative {
  position: relative;
  left: 20vw;
}
```

If you also use `vw` for the `width` and `height` properties of your images, it should work fine, as this will make all of your dimensions relative to the width of your viewport.

```css
#img1 {
    background-color: rgb(253, 7, 7);
    width: 70vw;
    height: 50vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 5vw;
}

#img2 {
    background-color: rgb(238, 138, 7);
    width: 70vw;
    height: 50vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 20vw;
    top: -7vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="img1">Img 1</div>
<div id="img2">Img 2</div>
```

Another possibility would be to use a grid lay-out (`display: grid`).

Comment: Hi Thomas,
thank you for your quick reply.
I am using vw and vh to place the pictures correctly.
But as soon as the screen gets smaller the overlapping pictures overlap not anymore as intended.
As far as I am aware I can use media queries to change the position of the pictures for different sizes.
The problem is I have +200 pictures that are all use at least a "left" or "right" property and a "top" bottom".
So at the moment the only solution I know to make it responsive is to manually change the position of +200 pictures for different screensizes.
Is there a better/faster solution?

Comment: @CapriSunMultiFruits,
I have edited my answer to give you a more detailed example of what I meant. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Hi Thomas,
Thank you for elaborating on your answer.
Now I am using vw for all relative positioning and it seems to make it a lot easier to keep a correct position.
Before I was combining vw and vh for position and this made it more complicated I think. 
Thank you for your help :) !